# What does the preprocessor do at the system compilation flow?

Tags: c, compilation

I've started reading *Computer Systems: A programmer's perspective (Beta draft)* book. It explains about system compilation from C source to executable program, for the example code at the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

I can't understand, why does the preprocessor has to put the content of the system header **stdio.h** on the source text as text? since the machine code that composes  **printf** function is merged with machine code that composes the example source code at the linking phase, what is exactly inserted at the source code text when the **#include**  directive is detected?

[System compilation picture from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv76K.png)

Did I get it all wrong? or is there something I do not know about all those phases?

Comment: the compiler doesn't handle external files. Only the preprocessor does, to expand their code so the compiler gets the complete piece of code to complete without looking anywhere else.

Comment: use `gcc -c -E name_of_source.c` to see how functions can be used without inducing a compiler error where a undefined symbol is not found.

Comment: It's not including the actual code for `printf`.  It's including the code that describes the interface, _i.e._ in your case, so that your source file understands `printf` is a symbol that describes a function, and that your arguments are the correct type.  Also, some things in header files do not describe link-time items at all.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the preprocessor has to put the content of the system header stdio.h on the source text as text?

That's the whole point of `#include` - what else would you expect `#include` to do?

> since the machine code that composes printf function is merged with machine code that composes the example source code at the linking phase,

`#include` has nothing to do with machine code. It works on source code only.

> what is exactly inserted at the source code text when the #include directive is detected?

The contents of stdio.h. If you're on a Linux system you can find this file at /usr/include/stdio.h. If you're on Windows you might want to search Program Files.

Note that `printf` is **not** defined in stdio.h; it is only declared.

If you want to know *exactly* what your source file looks like after preprocessing, and you're using GCC, you can run `gcc -E nameofyoursourcefile.c`

> Did I get it all wrong? or is there something I do not know about all those phases?

It appears that you think the source code for `printf` is in stdio.h. This is not the case.